# How to remove text from list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

List of dictionary is below

```
[{'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1,983,228 views'}, {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2,559,581 views'}, {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183,545 views'}, {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439,534 views'}]
```

How to remove from `views` and `,` from the from the `views` key, Expected Out

```
[{'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1983228'}, {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2559581'}, {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183545'}, {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439534'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videos = [
    {'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1,983,228 views'},
    {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2,559,581 views'},
    {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183,545 views'},
    {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439,534 views'}
]

for video in videos:
    video["views"] = "".join(filter(str.isdigit, video["views"]))

print(videos)
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1983228'}, {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2559581'}, {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183545'}, {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439534'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = [{'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1,983,228 views'}, {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2,559,581 views'}, {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183,545 views'}, {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439,534 views'}]

for k in d:
    k["views"] = k["views"].replace(",","").replace("views","").strip()

print(d)

[{'title': 'XXX#1092', 'views': '1983228'},
 {'title': 'xxEP#1091', 'views': '2559581'},
 {'title': 'xx', 'views': '183545'},
 {'title': ' Official Music Video', 'views': '439534'}]
```